# NSURLSession catch redirect not working

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, nsurlsession

I have a class:

```
class Test: UIViewController, NSURLSessionDelegate {

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: NSHTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest!) -> Void) {
        let responseHeaderFields = (response ).allHeaderFields as! [String : String]
        var nR = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: request.URL!, cachePolicy:  NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: NSTimeInterval(30))
        nR.allHTTPHeaderFields = NSHTTPCookie.requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies(NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(responseHeaderFields, forURL: response.URL!))

            for header in responseHeaderFields {
                nR.setValue(
                    header.1,
                    forHTTPHeaderField: header.0
                )
            }        
            completionHandler(nR)
        }

    func myMethod() {
          //some code...

          let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()
          let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
          session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: {
            (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) in
                guard let responseData = data else {
                    return
                }
                guard error == nil else {
                    return
                }
                //....
        }
    }

}
```

When i call `myMethod` i do post request to add item to cart. This post request create cookie cart and redirect me to another url. But my attempts to catch redirect and then set cookies and another headers data to next url is not working :( Any idea why ?

Comment: does it actually do redirect?

Comment: yes, i catch redirect, but new request with cookies and headers doesn't contain cart cookie at completionHandler

Comment: all what i want just move cookies from request to request...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but if you just want to move cookies from a request to another, you could use [NSHTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/).

Save the original response's cookies, and use the same url to retrieve them when you need them.

just go :

```
    NSArray *cookies = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[response allHeaderFields] forURL:originalResponse.URL];
   [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookies:cookies forURL:originalResponse.URL mainDocumentURL:nil];
```

And where you need to read the cookies just call:

```
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:originalResponse.URL];
```